# Metaphors about death

Tags: phrases, metaphors

What are some sayings or metaphors that would interact well with a massacre or calamity?
for example "The crows feasted for days"

Comment: See also: [writers.se]

Comment: The killing fields.

Comment: Heaven wept....

Answer (score 4):

Individual death:

- Met his Maker.
- Bought the farm.
- Kicked the bucket.
- Bought the big one.
- Is pushing up daisies.
- Went on to his reward.
- Shuffled off this mortal coil.

Huge number of deaths:

- genocide
- massacre
- carnage
- extinction
- bloodbath
- internecine
- life is cheap
- Armageddon
- depopulated
- mass carnage
- angel of death (biblical reference - see Passover)
- rained death (attack from the sky)
- scorched earth (destruction of property as well as killing of people)
- reign of terror (ongoing government-sanctioned killing)
- dropping like flies
- not a man left standing
- plague, epidemic, scourge (death by disease)
- smell of death in the air
- not a soul left to tell the tale
- ground littered with corpses
- corpses rotting in the streets

Comment: Your answer is much better researched than the question. +1 for effort.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't do any research. Those were all off the top of my head.

Comment: For a huge number 'statistic'.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck if you start with some of the specifics details.

If there was a lot of blood for example you could go with:

The "x" ran red with blood.
*substitute x with your choice of rivers, streets, halls etc.

The wet smell of iron hung in the air.

Or if there were fires burning, then the black ash could darken the sky.

Or if there were survivors then the moans of their suffering could fill the location.

Or you could just Lovecraft it and say it was incomprehensible in some respect. That works well if it's some inconceivably graphic scene.